# Facebook sharing debugger tells me that og:image is not specified in the page, but it is?

Tags: facebook, open-graph

I had read many articles and tried different solutions, but facebook debugger still tells me: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

In the head tag, I have

<meta property="og:image"

Other open graph attributes, like the page title and page descriptions are found properly.

I has PHP instructed to send a header no cache, and in .htaccess have also disabled caching.
I also had 
but removed it (PHP line commented) after I got no changed from the FB debugger.

If I use tthe Linkedin sharing debugger (Post Inspector), the image is shown correctly.

Site is a PHP site, no wordpress, and don't know if I can use an SEO plugin to help overcome issue.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isue solved. checked by setting Google into cookieless mode which showed a PHP error in the HEAD tag.
Solved and it's working now :)

The issue was that a PHP error was being written to the outpu HTML in the HEAD tag.